# Convert DataTable to JSON with only Value

Tags: c#, json

If I have a datatable in the following structure.

```
HostelName      FloorName   FlatName    Occupied    Vacant
Building One    Floor A         A           2          2
Building One    Floor A         B           0          4
Building One    Floor A         C           0          4
Building One    Floor A         D           0          4
Building One    Floor A         E           0          4
Building One    Floor B         F           0          4
Building One    Floor B         G           0          4
Building One    Floor B         H           0          4
Building One    Floor B         I           0          4
Building One    Floor B         J           0          4
```

I would like to serialize it as a JSON object where the HostelName,FloorName & FlatName columns are the nodes in the JSON object like:

```
{
    "Building One": {
        "Floor A": {
            "A": {
                "Occupied": "2",
                "Vacant": "2"
            },
            "B": {
                "Occupied": "0",
                "Vacant": "4"
            },
            "C": {
                "Occupied": "0",
                "Vacant": "4"
            },
            "D": {
                "Occupied": "0",
                "Vacant": "4"
            },
            "E": {
                "Occupied": "0",
                "Vacant": "4"
            }
        },
        "Floor B": {
            "F": {
                "Occupied": "0",
                "Vacant": "4"
            },
            "G": {
                "Occupied": "0",
                "Vacant": "4"
            },
            "H": {
                "Occupied": "0",
                "Vacant": "4"
            },
            "D": {
                "Occupied": "0",
                "Vacant": "4"
            },
            "I": {
                "Occupied": "0",
                "Vacant": "4"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Try to generate JSON using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: did you manage to query the data from the table at least? what are you having trouble with?

Comment: You want to group by any columns ? and then convert to json ?

Comment: I think that you should create an object with the same fields as the DB, and fill it with the values from the DB and serialize it to the json that you want.

Comment: What do you want to do? and what should we solve exactly?

Comment: I already converted the data to JSON format from sql itself.And I did it from c# also.But every where I am getting JSON format with the column names.I don't want that .I need JSON without column names

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is using a custom JSONConverter (in case of useing JSON.NET), learn about that [here (JSON.NET Implementing Custom Serialization)](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/).

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a finite amount of rooms on each floor, I would make the the rooms an array. The same goes for the floors too. Makes more sense and it's easier to work with if you're going to parse it later.

To write custom JSON you could use JSON.net's [JsonWriter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadingWritingJSON.htm). Then you could write it like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("Building One");
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("Floor A");
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("A");
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("Occupied");
    writer.WriteValue("2");
    writer.WritePropertyName("Vacant");
    writer.WriteValue("2");
    writer.WriteEnd();
    writer.WritePropertyName("B");
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("Occupied");
    writer.WriteValue("0");
    writer.WritePropertyName("Vacant");
    writer.WriteValue("4");
    writer.WriteEnd();
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Or with JTokens

```
JObject o = new JObject(
    new JProperty("Building One",
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("Floor A",
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("A",
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("Occupied", "2"),
                            new JProperty("Vacant", "2"))),
                    new JProperty("B",
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("Occupied", "0"),
                            new JProperty("Vacant", "4"))))))));
```